# «Пробуждение с грехом пополам». Возможно?

Tags: фразеология, значение-слов, лексическая-сочетаемость

Можно ли "проснуться с грехом пополам"? Одно из значений этого фразеологизма — прикладывая значительные усилия.

Answer (score 1):

В большом словаре русских поговорок:
[с грехом пополам](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/18743/%D0%A1_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC)
**1.** *Разг.* Кое-как, с большим усилием, с трудом.
**2.** *Устар.* Обманным путем, нечестно.

***С грехом пополам выпроводив** деда Щукаря, Давыдов решил пойти в школу и на месте определить, что еще можно сделать...* (М. Шолохов); *Хихикая в подушку и отчаянно краснея от собственных мыслей, **я с грехом пополам уснула**...* (Ю. Фирсанова); *Лишь грохнувшись с лавки и ощутимо приложившись затылком о каменной твердости дерево ножки, Ефим сумел вырваться из липкой паутины кошмара и, **с грехом пополам продрав глаза**, разглядел склонившуюся над ним давешнюю прачку* (И. Исайчев).

> **И день разгорался с грехом пополам**,
> и стал он палящ.
> Курортная шатия белых панам
> тащилась на пляж.
> Лев Лосев

*Можно ли "проснуться с грехом пополам"?* Да, думаю, что в контексте разговорного стиля так можно выразиться (= с трудом проснуться).
[Здесь](http://www.endic.ru/russaying/Greh-9902.html) есть еще фразеологизмы со словом "грех".

**Дополнение**

*[Просыпаюсь с грехом пополам.](https://books.google.ee/books?id=97ZhDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT17&lpg=PT17&dq=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D1%81%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC.%20%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%98%20%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F.&source=bl&ots=lfAFjdn6k6&sig=ACfU3U0_cSTHm92o2oyC7_VUGNcUgLDM-w&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiCuuDjlPPqAhVu_SoKHWn6BvYQ6AEwAnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D1%81%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC.%20%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%98%20%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F.&f=false)

Бессвязное блуждание

И судорожный сарказм

Проблемного выживания.*
Владимир Карнаухов